# Nginx Config for multiple urls

Tags: node.js, nginx, passenger, kibana

I am completely new to Nginx and using it for the first time .I have installed nginx and passenger url on my machine .Below is my config file

```
     #http {
    #passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
    # Use /usr/bin/node by default.
    #passenger_nodejs /usr/bin/nodejs;

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 10.X.XX.XX; 

    # Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
    location /general/ {
    root /var/www/app/general_pcap/public;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    # Turn on Passenger
    passenger_enabled on;
    # Tell Passenger that your app is a Node.js app
    passenger_startup_file app.js;
    passenger_app_type node;
    }

    #passenger_env_var ROOT_URL http://127.0.0.1;


location / {

        proxy_pass http://localhost:5601;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;  
}
}
#}
```

When  I hit the url 10.X.XX.X/generalPcap  I get no page found .How can I configure the config file so that when /generalPCAP is called it will redirect to my /var/www/courantapp/general_pcap/public
nodejs app located at .

And when I call 10.X.XX.X/kibana it will redirect to my kibana running on 9601.

Comment: Try changing your 'root' directive under location /generalPcap to an 'alias'

Comment: it gives me Cannot GET /generalPcap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created two conf files and was able to configure it .Had to add names of server in /etc/hosts file and it worked .